First and last nodes do not relocate shards/indices in excluded range from 64 node Elastic cluster
I am trying to replace storage for all 64 nodes in my Elasticsearch k8s cluster in batches, but when I exclude a range of nodes, for example first 32, Elastic relocate all indexes shards to other available nodes, but do not reallocate data from the node1 and node32 (always first and last from a range).
This is the command I use to exclude the node range:
PUT _cluster/settings
{
 "persistent" : {
   "cluster.routing.allocation.exclude._name" : [ "node1" ,"node2" ... ,"node32"]
 }
}

I notice the 1st and last node in the list never relocate shards for any ranges I set. Why this is happening?
I am using Elastic version "7.9.0".
Error response:
  GET cluster/allocation/explain
#! Deprecation: [types removal] Specifying types in document get requests is deprecated, use the /{index}/_doc/{id} endpoint instead.
{
 "error" : {
 "root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "index_not_found_exception",
    "reason" : "no such index [cluster]",
    "resource.type" : "index_expression",
    "resource.id" : "cluster",
    "index_uuid" : "_na_",
    "index" : "cluster"
  }
],
"type" : "index_not_found_exception",
"reason" : "no such index [cluster]",
"resource.type" : "index_expression",
"resource.id" : "cluster",
"index_uuid" : "_na_",
"index" : "cluster"
},
"status" : 404
}

GET _cluster/allocation/explain
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllocationExplainRequest[useAnyUnassignedShard=true,includeYesDecisions?=false]"
  }
],
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "unable to find any unassigned shards to explain [ClusterAllocationExplainRequest[useAnyUnassignedShard=true,includeYesDecisions?=false]"
},
 "status" : 400
}

GET _cluster/allocation/explain?include_yes_decisions=true
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "No shard was specified in the request which means the response should explain a randomly-chosen unassigned shard, but there are no unassigned shards in this cluster. To explain the allocation of an assigned shard you must specify the target shard in the request."
  }
],
"type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
"reason" : "No shard was specified in the request which means the response should explain a randomly-chosen unassigned shard, but there are no unassigned shards in this cluster. To explain the allocation of an assigned shard you must specify the target shard in the request."
},
"status" : 400
}


How does it behave when you only specify two nodes, then three, then four, etc?

Actually attempt to exclude only node1 and node32 also fail ... , it looks to be something with the big index 32 shards 1 replica

So it's always the same two nodes that fail, it has not necessarily anything to do with their position in the list... Can you add to your question the result you get from GET cluster/allocation/explain?

issue maybe related to the 7.9 version ...

Oops sorry, the endpoint is GET _cluster/allocation/explain with an underscore

added the output also for _cluster/allocation/explain , but it looks this api is only working when there is shards that are not allocated , in my case all shards are allocated just they dont want to move to other nodes

Can you add ?include_yes_decisions=true ?

included in the output

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.
